# Printing GWT Cell Table

Tags: gwt

As part of a recent project, I have created a Cell Table that holds a few million rows of data. This data can be exported to CSV, filtered, and a few other basic functions. The last bit of functionality that I want to add, is the ability to print out the contents of the Cell Table to a local printer. I've done some research online (Google Groups and all the intro GWT material), but as far as I can tell there is no method to print a widget's contents -- specifically a Cell Table. Does anyone have an idea of how to go about setting something like this up (obviously I expect no code -- a description would be great!)?

Comment: How is this data being loaded to your client app?

Comment: A simple async call sends the data to the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an idea on how to print GWT widgets in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/eea48bafbe8eed63?pli=1). The author of that post also placed his [Print class](http://gwt-print-it.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/br/com/freller/tool/client/Print.java) in a Google Code project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use a printer interface from js code.

http://javascript.about.com/od/events/a/print.htm

Several webs have a button like "print version" which generates an HTML page with plain custom style.

example - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

You can also easily generate pdf versions in either client or server. PDF is quite a good way to let user print a document.

more info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523851/gwt-printing-to-pdf